# Parsing XSD w/XDocument

Tags: c#, linq, xsd, linq-to-xml

I am having a heck of a time trying to parse a schema file... was hoping someone could help.

Here is what the xsd looks like

```
 <xs:element name="E1">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="E2" nillable="true" minOccurs="0">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="E3" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                            <xs:complexType>
                                <xs:sequence>
                                    <xs:element name="E4" nillable="true" minOccurs="0">
                                        <xs:complexType>
                                            <xs:sequence>
                                                <xs:element name="E5" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                                    <xs:complexType>
                                                        <xs:attribute name="A1" type="xs:integer" use="optional" />
                                                        <xs:attribute name="A2" type="xs:string" use="optional" />
                                                        <xs:attribute name="A3" type="xs:string" use="optional" />\
                                                    </xs:complexType>
                                                </xs:element>
                                            </xs:sequence>
                                        </xs:complexType>
                                    </xs:element>
                               </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                         </xs:complexType>
                     </xs:element>
```

This isn't complete, but enough to get the idea.  Here is the code I was trying to get the element name, followed by any attributes if they existed, but this is only returning the element names.

```
var xs = XNamespace.Get("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
var doc = XDocument.Load(sourceName + sourceApi + "Input.txt");
        foreach (var el in doc.Descendants(xs + "element"))
        {
            Trace.WriteLine("ANDY ------ " + el.Attribute("name").Value);
            foreach (var attr in el.Elements(xs + "attribute"))
            {
                Trace.WriteLine(attr.Attribute("name").Value);
            }
        }
```

This is outputing

Andy ----- E1
Andy ----- E2
Andy ----- E3
Andy ----- E4
Andy ----- E5

Where I want it to output

Andy ----- E1
Andy ----- E2
Andy ----- E3
Andy ----- E4
Andy ----- E5
A1
A2
A3

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`el.Elements` checks only the child elements, so there it return nothing. You should use `Descendants` or specify full path by `el.Elements(xs + "complexType").Elements(xs + "attribute")`:

```
var xs = XNamespace.Get("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
var doc = XDocument.Load(sourceName + sourceApi + "Input.txt");
foreach (var el in doc.Descendants(xs + "element"))
{
    Trace.WriteLine("ANDY ------ " + el.Attribute("name").Value);
    foreach (var attr in el.Elements(xs + "complexType").Elements(xs + "attribute"))
    {
        Trace.WriteLine(attr.Attribute("name").Value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found that the easiest way to deserialize schema is with the Visual Studio XSD command line utility.  From a Visual Studio Command Prompt, you can enter something like:

> xsd MySchema.xsd /CLASSES

The /CLASSES switch is used in case the xsd contains multiple classes.

The output in this case would be a file called "MySchema.cs".  This will contain an XmlSerializer class that can do the job of the XSD.

(Note that the .xsd file itself could have been generated by calling the same utility with the name of a .xml file as input.)

Comment: I don't want a class though.... I am trying to generate a script of all the element names with their child attributes.